# rspec mongoid validation of uniqueness

Tags: ruby-on-rails, validation, rspec, mongoid, validates-uniqueness-of

I would like to test the uniquness of User model.

My `User` model class looks like:

```rb
class User
  include Mongoid::Document
  field :email, type: String
  embeds_one :details

  validates :email,
      presence: true,
      uniqueness: true,
      format: {
        with: /\A([^@\s]+)@((?:[-a-z0-9]+\.)+[a-z0-9]{2,})\Z/i,
        on: :create
      },
      length: { in: 6..50 }

end
```

My rspec test which belongs to the model looks like:

```rb
...
before(:each) do
  FactoryGirl.create(:user, email: taken_mail)
end

it "with an already used email" do
  expect(FactoryGirl.create(:user, email: taken_mail)).to_not be_valid
end
```

After I executed `bundle exec rspec` it always raises the next error instead of passed with success:

```
Failure/Error: expect(FactoryGirl.create(:user, email: taken_mail)).to_not be_valid
     Mongoid::Errors::Validations:

       Problem:
         Validation of User failed.
       Summary:
         The following errors were found: Email is already taken
       Resolution:
         Try persisting the document with valid data or remove the validations.
```

If I use this it passes with success:

```
it { should validate_uniqueness_of(:email) }
```

I would like to use `expect(...)`. Can anybody help me out?

Comment: What if you try: `expect(FactoryGirl.build(:user, email: taken_mail)).to_not be_valid` ? using build instead of create

Comment: It works properly and tests passed but I do not know why the error gets raised when I use `create` method. What if I want to use `FactoryGirl.create(...)`
If you leave this in an answer I give you the point.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The issue is you are trying to persist an invalid object into the database, which throws an exception and breaks the test (because email is not unique), before even the test is done using the `expect` method.

The correct way is to use `build` here instead of `create`, which doesn't persist the object in the database, by  building the record only in memory and allowing your test to do its job. Therefore to fix it:

```
expect(FactoryGirl.build(:user, email: taken_mail)).to_not be_valid
```

Also note that is better to use `build` rather than `create` if you don't need to actually save the record in the database, since it's a cheaper operation and you will get the same outcome, unless for some reason your record must be saved to the database for your tests to work in a way you want them, such as saving the first record in in your example.